# Angular JS JSON Editor Error: [$compile:nonassign]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to use the [angular js editor](https://github.com/duychinhnguyenvn/angular-json-editor) (It is a directive which is built on top of [jquery json editor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor))

But i am getting the following error: [Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'jsonEditorInput' is non-assignable!](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=jsonEditorInput)

Please find my code as follows:

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",["angular-json-editor"]);
   app.controller("myController",function($scope){

      $scope.people={            
                "name": "Mr A. Payne",
                "age": 35,
                "company name": "ARAMARK Ltd." ,
                "address": {
                  "street": "30 Commercial Road",
                  "city area/district" : "Fratton",
                  "city/town/village" : "PORTSMOUTH",
                  "county": "Hampshire",
                  "postal code": "PO1 1AA"
                }            
      };
      

    
      $scope.onError=function(err){
        alert(err);
      };

    $scope.options={
     "mode": "code",
        "modes": ['tree','form', 'code', 'text'],     
        "history": false
    };
  $scope.download=function(){
   ga('send', {
     'hitType': 'event',          // Required.
     'eventCategory': 'button',   // Required.
     'eventAction': 'download',      // Required.
     'eventLabel': 'nav buttons',
     'eventValue': 1
   });
  };
   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html ng-app="myApp">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Node All Admin | </title>

    <link href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.css"></script>
    <link href="lib/angular-json-editor/angular-json-editor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body ng-controller="myController" class="nav-md">
    <json-editor-input model="people"/>


    <br/><br/><br/> 
    <json-editor-input model="people" on-error="onError(err)"/>

    <br/><br/><br/> 
    <div json-editor model="people" options="options" style="height: 400px;"/>
</body>
  

<script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jsoneditor/dist/jsoneditor.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-json-editor/angular-json-editor.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: create demo that replicates this issue

Comment: @charlietfl do you mean to create a fiddle? I am new, how to add the json editor css and js file links, as they are in github.

Comment: might find [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) simpler to set up for this. Can use  https://rawgit.com/ for resources